# How to export from R to a calc ods file in multiple sheets

Tags: r, export, calc, ods

I try to export three dataframes to a single calc file (ods), but I don't see how to specify the sheet I'm writing into.

I tried the readODS package which has a write_ods function, but in the documentation I see not mention of a sheet specification.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know how it was 4 years ago but now there is an option to append to the ods file.

```
write_ods(df1, filename, sheet = "df1")

write_ods(df2, filename, sheet = "df2", append = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is your problem?

When you have a data.frame and export it using `readODS::write_ods`, then your output is a .ods file. Or do you want to export mutliple data.frames in one file using multiple sheets?

Comment: I edited my question, I hope it's clearer now. I want to write several data frames in a single ods.

Comment: short description from the rio package: OpenDocument Spreadsheet (.ods), using write_ods. (Currently only single-sheet exports
are supported.) Can you use the write.xlsx from the openxlsx package, open it in your program and convert it to an .ods file? It is a bit of a detour, but hopefully it solves your problem.

Comment: that would be a workaround, but I try to automatise my process as much as possible, so not ideal.

Comment: to automatise at least a bit you can save the data.frames in a list `list_save <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df3)` and pass the list to the `write.xlsx` function

Comment: ok thank you. Has anyone some tips for automatise the "convert xls to ods" part ?